# KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs when trying to send a message with KafkaProducer.send()

Tags: python, docker, pyspark, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'm using the following docker-compose file :

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  kafka:
    image: bitnami/kafka:3.3.2
    container_name: kafka
    hostname: kafka
    restart: "no"
    links:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 9092:9092
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_CFG_REQUEST_TIMEOUT_MS: "120000" # Set to 120 seconds
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://:29092,EXTERNAL://:9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: INTERNAL://kafka:9092,EXTERNAL://localhost:9092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: INTERNAL:PLAINTEXT,EXTERNAL:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: INTERNAL
      ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER: yes
      KAFKA_AUTO_CREATE_TOPICS_ENABLE: "true" # Enable automatic topic creation

  zookeeper:
    image: bitnami/zookeeper:3.7.1
    container_name: zookeeper
    hostname: zookeeper
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
      - "2888:2888"
      - "3888:3888"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
      ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN: yes

  spark-app:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - ./src:/usr/src/app
    depends_on:
      - kafka
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "4040:4040" # Spark application UI port

  spark-master:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.1.2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=master
      - SPARK_MASTER_PORT=7077
      - SPARK_MASTER_WEBUI_PORT=8080 # Master UI port
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    ports:
      - "8080:8080" # Exposing Spark master UI to host
      - "7077:7077" # Exposing Spark master communication port to host

  spark-worker:
    image: bitnami/spark:3.1.2
    environment:
      - SPARK_MODE=worker
      - SPARK_MASTER_URL=spark://spark-master:7077
      - SPARK_WORKER_CORES=1
      - SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=2G
      - SPARK_RPC_AUTHENTICATION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_RPC_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_LOCAL_STORAGE_ENCRYPTION_ENABLED=no
      - SPARK_SSL_ENABLED=no
    depends_on:
      - spark-master
    ports:
      - "8081:8081" # Worker UI port (optional, if you want to access worker UI)
```

and the following Dockerfile:

```
# Use an official Python runtime as a parent image with a compatible version
FROM python:3.8-slim

# Set the working directory in the container
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install Java (required for Spark)
RUN apt-get update && \
    apt-get install -y default-jre && \
    apt-get clean;

# Download and install a stable version of Spark compatible with Python 3.8
ENV APACHE_SPARK_VERSION 3.1.2
RUN apt-get -y update && \
    apt-get install -y wget && \
    wget --no-verbose https://archive.apache.org/dist/spark/spark-$APACHE_SPARK_VERSION/spark-$APACHE_SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz && \
    tar -xzf spark-$APACHE_SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz -C /usr/local && \
    rm spark-$APACHE_SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.7.tgz

ENV SPARK_HOME /usr/local/spark-$APACHE_SPARK_VERSION-bin-hadoop2.7
ENV PATH $PATH:$SPARK_HOME/bin

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /usr/src/app
COPY ./src /usr/src/app

# Copy the requirements.txt file into the container at /usr/src/app
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app

# Install any needed packages specified in requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Make port 8080 available to the world outside this container
EXPOSE 8080

# Define environment variable
ENV NAME World

# Run 
CMD ["python", "./main.py"]
```

I'm trying to run a simple python script to check if my setup is working correctly where I create a kafka producer and a kafka consumer and try to send a message through the first and recieve it through the latter. It looks something like this:

```
from kafka import KafkaProducer, KafkaConsumer
import time
import socket


def wait_for_kafka():
    up = False
    while not up:
        try:
            # Try to connect to the Kafka server and check a simple operation
            KafkaConsumer(bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092')
            up = True
            print("Kafka is up and running!")
        except (socket.error, Exception):
            print("Kafka not ready, waiting...")
            time.sleep(5)  # wait 5 seconds before trying again


# Wait for Kafka to be ready
wait_for_kafka()

# Kafka producer configuration
print("Creating Kafka producer...")
producer = KafkaProducer(
    bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092',  # Use the hostname of your Kafka container
    value_serializer=lambda v: str(v).encode('utf-8')
)

# Kafka consumer configuration
print("Creating Kafka consumer...")
consumer = KafkaConsumer(
    'test-topic',  # Replace with your Kafka topic
    bootstrap_servers='kafka:9092',  # Use the hostname of your Kafka container
    group_id='my-group',
    value_deserializer=lambda x: x.decode('utf-8')
)

# Produce a message
print("Sending message...")
producer.send('test-topic', value='Hello, Kafka!')

# Wait for Kafka to process the message (adjust as needed)
print("Waiting for Kafka...")
time.sleep(2)

# Consume and print the message
print("Consuming message...")
for message in consumer:
    print(f"Received message: {message.value}")
```

When the code is run through the container, i get the following log:

```
Kafka is up and running!
Creating Kafka producer...
Creating Kafka consumer...
Sending message...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./main.py", line 40, in <module>
    producer.send('test-topic', value='Hello, Kafka!')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 576, in send
    self._wait_on_metadata(topic, self.config['max_block_ms'] / 1000.0)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kafka/producer/kafka.py", line 702, in _wait_on_metadata
    raise Errors.KafkaTimeoutError(
kafka.errors.KafkaTimeoutError: KafkaTimeoutError: Failed to update metadata after 60.0 secs.
```

I tried both increasing the timeout time to 2 mins (but it still waits for 60 secs only) and  allow topic creation but it's no use.